# How to use untyped JS NPM modules in TypeScript for node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Ive just started experimenting with TypeScript and I have a following project structure:

```
-src
| index.ts
| MyClass.ts
-node_modules
 -npm_js_module
 | index.js
 | utils.js
 - src
  | someModuleFile.js
  | someModuleFile2.js
```

I need to use functions from npm_js_module/index.js (and from pm_js_module/src but these are required by index.js) in MyClass.ts. This module is untyped and has no typing available online by someone else. Is it even possible to use untyped JavaScript NPM module in typescript project?

When I am trying to compile this project I am getting this error:

```
error TS6059: File '/node_modules/npm_js_module/index.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
error TS6059: File '/node_modules/npm_js_module/utils.js'' is not under 'rootDir' '/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs" : true,
    "baseUrl" : "./",
    "paths": {
      "*" : ["./node_modules/@types/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/npm_js_module/index.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "./node_modules/npm_js_module/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and package.json like this:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.30"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm_js_module": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

I am using this way to import that module: `import * as mymodule from 'npm_js_module';` where VScode shows this error in a code: `Property 'login' does not exist on type '(loginData: any, options: any, callback: any) => void'.` and when I try to compile this there are errors like I wrote above.

Comment: Ive found typings for that module so no hacks needed, thanks to everyone. Ive tried @Will s solution and it worked too, just too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not crystal clear but it is buried in the documentation:

[Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

If you scroll down, you'll see a section labeled: 
**export = and import = require()**

> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module.

And that shows an example:

```
import zip = require("./ZipCodeValidator");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 3 possible solutions for your problem.

1. Using normal Javascript `import jsModule = require('npm_js_module');`
2. Create a dummy definition for your module and include it manually.
3. BEST WAY: Create the correct definition and do a pull request to the official repository.

The first solution should work for you, just require it as a normal node.js module. (If you are using the latest version of node 8.5 you will be able to use ES6 import style by activating the special flag `node --experimental-modules main.mjs`) but I dont recommend it since it's not finallized..